# commerce_cardonfile_form_alter() not firing on the checkout form in Drupal Commerce

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, e-commerce, drupal-modules

I am using the Card on File Module v2 with Stripe and for some reason the commerce_cardonfile_form_alter is not being called at all, as it is there to alter the checkout form and add the appropriate "store credit card" checkbox. I checked this by adding die; after the start of the function and it did not do this as expected.
I have enabled "Card on File" for the Stripe module.

Answer (score 0):

- Install [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module, or use xDebug,
- write a [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to check out your forms id
- in form_alter `dpm($form);`
- write your alterations in a if condition there or implement a proper [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)